# Can I use Perfect perfect continuous tense in these sentences?

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

1) I have lived in London for 4 years *(I have been living in London for 4 years)*

2) I have worked here since 1990 *(I have been working here since 1990)*

example #1 from the [video](https://youtu.be/hqX8gANPN-E?t=467)

Comment: Yes, you can, but in general it's better to keep sentences simple unless you have some specific reason to use the continuous tense.  Although many native speakers just do whatever feels right, so go for it  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are technically correct, but using present perfect continuous is arguably less ambiguous. It's a matter of preference, but I would suggest reducing ambiguity where doing so doesn't add complexity.

Why? Less ambiguity means less cognitive overhead, which is the primary reason most english communications specialists argue to favor simplicity.

Comment: A case in point of how adding detail can reduce complexity is adjective overuse 'ex: "he was an angry fuming mad onerous beast."'